# Assigning a subset of properties with the Object.assign() method

Tags: javascript, object, dom, iframe, assign

I am developing a chrome extension and I am creating a side panel using an `iframe` element.
I have an object that stores styles for the corresponding `iframe`:

```
const sidePanelStyle = {
    background: 'white',
    // some other vars 
};
```

I create the `iframe` and assign my settings:

```
let sidePanel = document.createElement('iframe');
Object.assign(sidePanel.style, sidePanelStyle);
```

Everything works, but when before I did

```
sidePanel.style = Object.assign(sidePanel.style, sidePanelStyle);
```

it did not merge anything into the `sidePanel.style` (I expected that `.assign()` returns a merged object, as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)).

I am new to JS, so the questions are:

1. What exactly I am missing with `Object.assign()`?
2. What is the best practice to assign multiple settings properties to an object from the existing framework and what is the best practice to keep them in my source code (a separate
   module? one or more objects? etc.).

While returning a merged object is redundant (the `.assign()` method merges everything into the first argument), I am still curios why it does not work, when the object is returned.

```js
const sidePanelStyle = {
 background: 'gray',
 height: '100%',
 padding: '20px',
 width: '400px',
 position: 'fixed',
 top: '0px',
 right: '0px',
 zIndex: '9000000000000000000',
};

let sidePanel = document.createElement('iframe');
// this works fine
// Object.assign(sidePanel.style, sidePanelStyle);

// this doesn't
sidePanel.style = Object.assign(sidePanel.style, sidePanelStyle);


document.body.appendChild(sidePanel);
```

Comment: That said, there's no reason for the `sidePanel.style = Object.assign(sidePanel.style, sidePanelStyle);` in `sidePanel.style = Object.assign(sidePanel.style, sidePanelStyle);`. `Object.assign` does return the merged object, but it merges the object into the first object, so if you already have a reference to that object, there's no need for the assignment. Just `Object.assign(sidePanel.style, sidePanelStyle);` is sufficient. (It returns the object it receives as the first parameter in case you're creating it, e.g. `const obj = Object.assign({}, ...);`.)

Comment: Inserted a snippet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quirk of the `style` property on DOM elements, which is an unfortunate throwback to the early days of web browsers where things were added a bit...willy nilly with some very, very strange semantics.

When you *read* the `style` property of an element, you get an object that has properties for the inline styles. But when you *write* to it, what you write is treated as though it were a string or `null`. (Although [officially](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#the-elementcssinlinestyle-mixin), it's supposed to be read-only. It isn't treated that way in today's browsers, though.)

Moral of the story: Don't write to it (unless you're writing `null` to completely clear it).

So when you do:

```
sidePanel.style = Object.assign(sidePanel.style, sidePanelStyle);
```

...what happens is:

1. The styles are successfully added to `sidePanel.style`, because `Object.assign` writes to the object given in its first argument, and then
2. The object it returns (also `sidePanel.style`) is converted to string and interpreted as style properties. (Although, again, it's supposed to be read-only.)

But when you convert it to string, the resulting string is `"[object CSSStyleDeclaration]"`, which can't be converted to styles, so you wipe out the styles on the element.

Here's a simpler demonstration of what's going on:

```js
const example = document.getElementById("example");
example.style.color = "blue";
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("example.style.color before: " + example.style.color);
    // Assigning it to itself, which is effectively what
    // your code with `Object.assign` was doing
    example.style = example.style;
    console.log("example.style.color after:  " + example.style.color);
    console.log("String(example.style): " + String(example.style));
}, 800);
```

```html
<div id="example">This is the example div</div>
```

As you've seen, there's no reason to write back to it anyway, as the properties are added to it because it's the first argument to `Object.assign`.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I had this gut feeling that it is related to `.style` implementation, but it is not obvious.

Comment: Indeed, very much not obvious. :-)